# Setting start and end headings during Pure Pursuit path generation

Tags: path-planning

I've recently been looking into the Pure Pursuit algorithm, and have found [this post](https://www.chiefdelphi.com/t/paper-implementation-of-the-adaptive-pure-pursuit-controller/166552) from FRC Team 1712 which has a great explanation on how to implement it. However, a part that confused me was the Path smoothing algorithm. Here is code for that (which I have written in C++20 based on [FRC Team 3256's implementation of the algorithm](https://github.com/Team3256/warriorlib/blob/master/src/main/java/frc/team3256/warriorlib/auto/purepursuit/Path.java#L85)):

```cpp
// note that this code needs support for `constexpr std::vector`s, meaning you need
// a compiler that supports that in C++20 (such as GCC v12)

#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

struct Waypoint
{
  double x;
  double y;

  // ... (other data doesn't matter for this algorithm)
}

struct PathBuilder::Util
{
  using PathVector = std::vector<Waypoint>;

  constexpr static PathVector smooth(const PathVector &path,
                                     const double tolerance,
                                     const double a, const double b)
  {
    // algorithm borrowed from FRC Team 2168, cleaned up using
    // FRC Team 3256's implementation
    PathVector newPath(path);
    double change = tolerance;
    while (change >= tolerance)
    {
      change = 0.0;
      for (int i = 1; i < path.size() - 1; ++i)
      {
        const Waypoint &oldPoint = path[i];
        const Waypoint &prevPoint = newPath[i - 1];
        const Waypoint &nextPoint = newPath[i + 1];

        Waypoint &currPoint = newPath[i];
        auto currXCopy = currPoint.x, currYCopy = currPoint.y;

        currPoint.x += a * (oldPoint.x - currPoint.x) +
                       b * (prevPoint.x + nextPoint.x - 2 * currPoint.x);

        currPoint.y += a * (oldPoint.y - currPoint.y) +
                       b * (prevPoint.y + nextPoint.y - 2 * currPoint.y);

        change += std::abs(currXCopy - currPoint.x);
        change += std::abs(currYCopy - currPoint.y);
      }
    }

    return newPath;
  }
}
```

The problem I have with this code is that it never awknowledges or uses the start direction/heading or the desired end direction/heading of the robot, which means that it could generate a path in a different direction than what the robot is facing. I also looked into other sources, such as [this by `vinesmsuic` on a GitHub blog](https://vinesmsuic.github.io/2020/09/29/robotics-purepersuit/#smoothing), but often found this same "simpler" algorithm. However, looking at other implementations, such as [this one by `zhm-real` on GitHub](https://github.com/zhm-real/MotionPlanning/blob/master/Control/Pure_Pursuit.py#L232), they often use Reed-Shepps paths or Cubic/Quintic Splines (in fact, they mention using Quintic Splines in the paper by FRC Team 1712 instead of this smoothing algorithm).

This led to a few questions:

- How could you tell the "simpler method" the desired heading and the start heading? I had two ideas for this:

  - Create an extra point in the direction of where the robot is pointing whenever you create a path, so it smooths around that point and makes it easier for the robot to follow (I haven't tested this) OR
  - Just don't do anything to the path and let Pure Pursuit handle it on its own. (Doesn't this defeat the purpose of path smoothing?)
- Is this "simpler method" better or worse than using Reed-Shepps or Cubic/Quintic Splines? Which one is the "best", or are they all equally comparable/does it really matter practically which one is used?

Right now, I'm thinking the best method is the first option for the first question (adding an extra point) and that this simpler smoothing algorithm will probably work fine after doing that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, `constexpr` was added in C++11.  So you might only need that.

Comment: @Ben Support for `constexpr std::vector`s only arrived in C++20: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241909/cannot-create-constexpr-stdvector